# How to get dynamic count(id) while getting the dropdown filter value through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to get dynamic count(id) while getting the dropdown filter value through Ajax?

Don't know how to achieve this:

I want to get dynamic city count rows while the city dropdown list is fetched through Ajax and display it in on the top of the page?

See the attached image: countRows

[image]

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(city_id) FROM schools";
$query=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$number_filter_row = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, $sql));
$number_filter_rows = $number_filter_row[0];
$textLine="Best Play Schools ($number_filter_rows)";
```

Comment: @curious may I know the reason for downvoting?

Comment: i understand your frustration but only the person who down-voted you will be able to answer that so no pt in asking me

Comment: oh okay. @curious So is there no way to find that out?

Comment: no Rohit unfortunately there isn't any. as a welcome gesture to SO, i hv upvoted u now wch will take care of a couple of downvotes. hope u wont mind it:)